# Parsing unstructured data

Tags: php, parsing, pattern-matching

Here is the data i need to parse :

```
Date    Page impressions    Clicks  Page CTR    Page eCPM   Estimated earnings 2010-12-11   542 17  3.14%   7.13    3.87 Totals 542 17          3.87 Averages   542 17  3.14%   7.13    3.87
```

and i need to extract the last value 3.87. I know this can be done very easily using awk. But are there any solutions to convert this into an array based on the space seperation ?

Comment: the last value is 3.87 - not 3.17!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = preg_split("/[ \\t]+/", $str);
```